# AngularJs ng-repeat 2D array in table, each subarray one column

Tags: arrays, angularjs, 2d, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array and I need to put that array in table.

```
$scope.testArr=[
    {'first':[
            { 'value':'1_1', 'rolle':'one1' },
            { 'value':'2_1', 'rolle':'two1' },
            { 'value':'3_1', 'rolle':'three1'}  
        ]
    },
    {'second': [
            { 'value':'1_2', 'rolle':'one2' },
            { 'value':'2_2', 'rolle':'two2' },
            { 'value':'3_2', 'rolle':'three2' } 
        ]
    }
];
```

Resulting table should have 4 columns, each subarray should be one(or two) column(s). Like this:

```
one1 | 1_1 | one2 | 1-2
two1 | 2_1 | two2 | 2_2   
three1|3_1 | three2|3_2
```

So far I got this. Its only the first subarray:

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="test in testArr">
        <tr ng-repeat="t1 in test.first">
            <td> {{t1.rolle}} </td> 
            <td> {{t1.value}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I add the second subarray as column? It's not necessary need to be a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.testArr = [{
        'first': [{
            'value': '1_1',
            'rolle': 'one1'
        }, {
            'value': '2_1',
            'rolle': 'two1'
        }, {
            'value': '3_1',
            'rolle': 'three1'
        }]
    }, {
        'second': [{
            'value': '1_2',
            'rolle': 'one2'
        }, {
            'value': '2_2',
            'rolle': 'two2'
        }, {
            'value': '3_2',
            'rolle': 'three2'
        }]
    }];

});
```

```css
td {
  border:solid 1px grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="test in testArr">
        <tr ng-repeat="t1 in test.first">
            <td>{{t1.rolle}}</td>
            <td>{{t1.value}}</td>
            <td>{{testArr[1].second[$index].rolle}}</td>
            <td>{{testArr[1].second[$index].value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling with indexes all day. U saved me.

Comment: What if you don't want to repeat the <tbody> element. So you only want to loop the array and then repeat the <tr> and have one <tbody>. How to do that?

Comment: @Robert did you ever figure out how to do something like that?