# nested arrays with ng-repeat and table html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to take this json place it into a HTML table.

```
    "columns" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 0,
        "column_name" : "Column 1",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 0,
                "task" : "Task 1"
            }, 
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "task" : "Task 2"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "column_name" : "Column 2",
        "cards" : [ 
            {
                "id" : 0,
                "task" : "Task 3"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I have done quite a bit of searching on SO and cannot find why it is not doing what I expect.

https://jsfiddle.net/6nh100ca/9/

This is what I am expecting.

```
**Column 1 | Column 2**
Task 1   | Task 3
Task 2   |
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20063394/3279550
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-grouping-nested-ngrepeat-lists-in-angularjs.htm
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607425/3279550

This is what I have

```
    <table >
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="column in entity.columns">{{column.column_name}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="column in entity.columns" >
            <tr ng-repeat="card in column.cards">
                <td >{{card.task}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You should look into one of the table directives like `ui-grid`. Much better than making your own custom table

Comment: are you looking something like that https://jsfiddle.net/6nh100ca/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick with creating your own `<table>` manually, you need to pre-process your data object in order to fit the row logic. Try something like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nh100ca/12/):

Add this in your controller:

```
 $scope.rowColumns = [];
    $scope.columns.forEach(function(column, columnIndex){
        column.cards.forEach(function (card, rowIndex){
            if (!$scope.rowColumns[rowIndex])
                $scope.rowColumns[rowIndex] = [];
            $scope.rowColumns[rowIndex][columnIndex] = card;
        });
    });
    console.log($scope.rowColumns);
```

Then add this in your html:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="row in rowColumns">
      <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
           {{cell.task}}
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: That was exactly it. Only I had been hopping to not have to rearrange the data using the controller. Which seems a bit naive now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`column.columnName` should be `column.column_name` as per your example data, there after you could have two `ng-repeat` over a `data` where you will be actually have 1st `ng-repeat` over `tbody` & then the another will appear on `tr`. I'd prefer this approach when I have small data set. For larger data set the answer given by @Tiago is fine.

```
<table >
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in entity.columns">{{column.columnName}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="column in entity.columns" >
        <tr ng-repeat="card in column.cards">
            <td >{{card.task}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this was not what I expected. 

It showed the following.
```
|Column 1|Column 2 |
|Task1      |                 |
|Task2      |                 |
|Task3      |                 |

I would have expected the Task 3 to be in the second column

Comment: I don't like this at all. You are repeating tbody every time, which makes no sense

Comment: @iberbeu what problem you are seeing with it, Its valid HTML.. I know repeating over a time is what you aren't agree?

Comment: Your answer is actually right, so I will remove the downvote. Anyway I would like to know how to do this without repeating the tbody section because sometimes it is just not required and it makes no sense to repeat if not needed

Comment: @iberbeu but that would need another filter, or manual filtering, but yes, I noted your point, for large data set we should reformat/filter data before rendering(with single `ng-repeat`) otherwise for smaller data I'd prefer my approach, as per me it would not harm anything on page.

Comment: @iberbeu here you go, you could remove downvote now, if you want, Thanks for heads up, cheers :)